# Proof by induction of Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence, induction

I am analyzing different ways to find the time complexities of algorithms, and am having a lot of difficulty trying to solve this specific recurrence relation by using a proof by induction.

My RR is:
   T(n) <= 2T(n/2) + √n

I am assuming you would assume n and prove n-1? Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume T(0) = 0, T(1) = 1 (since you haven't given any trivial cases).
Thus, we have: T(2) = 3.41, T(4) = 8.82, T(6) = 14.57, T(8) = 20.48, T(10) = 26.51. This seems like being a linear function.

So, we could assume `T(n) <= C * n + o(n).`

This can be proven by induction. Suppose `T(k) <= C*(k) + o(k) = C*(k) + o(n).` for each `k<n`.

We should prove `T(n) <= C*n + o(n).`
Using the recurrence, `T(n) <= 2*T(n/2) + sqrt(n) <= 2*(C*(n/2) + o(n)) + sqrt(n) = C*n + (2*o(n) + sqrt(n)) = C*n + o(n)`.

Thus, we have proven `T(n) <= C*n + o(n)`, which guarantees that `T(n)` is at least `O(n)`.

Also, it can be shown that the solution of `T(x) = 2T(x/2) + sqrt(x), T(0)=0, T(1)=1` is `T(x) = (2x-sqrt(2x))/(2-sqrt(2))`.

Comment: nice response, do you know a generic way of analytically solving the recurrence like T(x) = 2T(x/2) + sqrt(x)?

Comment: @Vahan Simonyan These equations can be solved using [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). Even more complex recurrences may be solved by [Akra–Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

Comment: As I understood Master theorem or Akra-Bazzi theorem answering to the question how T function behaves asymptotically. I am just want to know how you got that (2x-sqrt(2x))/(2-sqrt(2)) is the solution of T(x) = 2T(x/2) + sqrt(x), T(0)=0, T(1)=1 equation? Of course I can verify that by putting solution into equation, but is there some generic method for solving this kind of equations? Is it somehow related to differential equations?

Answer (score 0):

If using induction to prove, then assumption would be true for K and prove for 2*k or 2^k.

First, check for T(1):

T(1) <= 2T(1/2) + √n

(Assuming T(1/2) = 1)  T(1) = 2 + √n <= O(√n log n)

Now, assuming it to be true for T(k).

=> T(k) <= O(√n log n)
T(k) <= 2T(k/2) + √n <= c(√n log n)

Proving for, T(2k):

T(2k) <= 2T(2k/2) + √(2k)
=> T(2k) <= 2(c(√k log k) + √(2k)
=> T(2k) <= √2 * [2(c(k log k) + √(2k)] //(Inequality follows)
=> T(2k) <= [c'(2k log 2k)]
=> T(2k) <= O(√n log n)

Growth rates:

(c < log n < log2n < √n < n < n log nn < n log n < n(1.1) < n2 < n3 < n4 < 2n)